# 15.10 will only start with `nomodeset`

Tags: drivers, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I'm not sure what started the problem; I don't think I even did an `apt-get update`, but now I cannot start my laptop without adding `nomodeset` to the GRUB command-line.

Going without it either yields a black screen, or a warning of "Low graphics mode". Trying to fix the problem or cancel out of the warning seems to lock me out (can't even get to a virtual terminal).

My system is a Thinkpad T420, with an Optimus Nvidia + Intel graphics.

Currently running with nvidia-352 and bumblebee, and tried upgrading to the Oibaf intel drivers, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: I believe that you would need to remove the nvidia drivers prior to using the Oibaf repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers 355.

But first uninstall every NVIDIA related software you have had installed before.

This includes removing the bumblebee packages as well, they will be replaced with nvidia-prime.

Open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee  
sudo reboot
```

Then (re)-install the NVIDIA drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Switch between intel and nvidia graphics by using **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles**.

Note : In case you used **any GPU drivers related PPA's** - **purge them before installing** as well !

Comment: Thank you, that works. Odd thing is: I had Bumblebee working just yesterday; I still wonder what went awry.

Comment: Might have to take the accepted answer away. Updated to 4.2.0-19, and nvidia-prime started showing similar behavior.

Can't use my nvidia card at all right now, but it is also always on, killing my battery.

Comment: @SlightlyCuban : Maybe something went wrong when the new kernel 4.2.0-19 was installed. Everything was working before, so it is proved that the installation instructions are correct. Now you have 3 options : 1.) Boot the system with the old kernel and wait for the next kernel version to be released or purge and reinstall the current kernel. 2.) Uninstall and reinstall the NVIDIA drivers 355. 3.) Purge the NVIDIA drivers 355 and install the new official NVIDIA drivers 358, which bring along many bug fixes and improvements. :)

Comment: correction: it was nvidia-358 that seems to be the cause of the problem. Either it would always boot with the discrete card, or only boot in low graphics. 4.2.0-19 + nvidia-355 seems to be "back to normal."